# updating Angular 4 to newest Angular will make affect with our modules and things?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am in a big project with the new team, but I do love to know how to make upgrade this Angular 4 to newest by safe? I am also new in Angular, newest Angular is better than old :D I think so :D

in this project, we have a lot of modules in app.modules.ts, I am afraid if I update things there will break our project,

Does anyone get to suggest to make a safe upgrade??
should I change the syntax also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the official **migration checklist** from Angular:

https://update.angular.io/

Depending on the size and complexity of your project, the migration can be more or less complex. You should do it anyway in my opinion.

RxJS 6 contains some breaking changes that might be tricky to understand for beginners. Be careful and understand what you are doing.

Comment: ohh no, i just saw my local angular still 1.4.2, i think it will be very hard to handle error for this old angular :(

Comment: In that case you are using AngularJS, which is different from the new Angular. You cannot just migrate to a new version, I am afraid you will have to rewrite most of your application...

Comment: It really depends on the complexity of your project. I am not familiar with AngularJS, but I highly doubt you can easily switch to Angular without changing a lot of code.

Comment: i read some syntax on my project almost same like the new angular , and on the ng v i check , it didnt say angularJs , but it is angular/cli : 1.4.2

Comment: Oh well that's the angular command line - it is different. Then you are probably using the new angular. You can see the version in the package.json ("@angular/core")

Comment: "@angular/core": "^4.2.4", so it is angular 4 ??

Comment: Yes :) Use the migration guide from my answer